# How can I force a bound datagrid to refresh the contents?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I am relatively new to silverlight development and have encountered the following scenario:

I have a DataGrid that is bound to a Domain DataSource.  Occasionally an update will be done to the data through an outside entity.  The DataSource is subsequently reloaded through a Clear() followed by a Load().

The problem is that when this is done, the data in the grid does not refresh unless one of the fields that changes is part of the key.  Otherwise, it appears that a cached version of the previous data for the entity is displayed.

I was able to work around this by adding a timestamp to the Dataset being returned and make that a part of the key, but in my mind this is a hack that should not be necessary.  What would be the proper way of refreshing the data?

Answer (score 0):

I Hope you are followin MVVm structure.

Change the list to an observeable collection and I hope you are binding it from xaml

Here's the code that might work for you.

```
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Customer> _MyList = 
        new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> MyList
    {
        get { return _MyList; }  
    } 

    public MainPage()
    {                      
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;

        MyList.Add(new Customer{ _nome = "Josimari", _idade = "29"});
        MyList.Add(new Customer{_nome = "Wesley", _idade = "26"});
        MyList.Add(new Customer{_nome = "Renato",_idade = "31"});

        OnPropertyChanged("MyList"); // This only works if you use bindings.
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyList.Add(new Customer{_nome = "Maiara",_idade = "18"});   

        OnPropertyChanged("MyList"); // This only works if you use bindings.
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged( string propertyName )
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    } 
}
```

Let me know if it doesnot work.